# JAVA- Program to check whether the two sets of lists of numbers are the same

Tags: java, set, intersection

My program generates two sets in memory, which I do not want to write them to a file. Each set has a set of lines. Each line is a series of numbers. I want to check if these two files have the same set of lines in java (java is must), efficiently.

For eg:

```
set1 :
1 2 3  
3 4 5 6  
1 2 4 5 7  
8  
7  
1 2 4  

set2 :  
7  
3 4 5 6  
1 2 4 5 7  
1 2 3  
8  
1 2 4
```

So, the set of lines are the same in case of set1 and set2, they are just jumbled. So, for these two sets as input, my algorithm in java should return true. Could you please help me in this regard. I implemented it using hashtables, however it is of little use.

Comment: how do you store your sets in memory? I mean what kind of data structure are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using `HashSet<String[]>` or `HashSet<List<String>>`?

Comment: For each file, read each line as one `List<Integer>` per line, store those lists in a `HashSet`. Then if `set1.containsAll(set2) && set2.containsAll(set1)`, you're good to go. Or just store each line as a `String` if you aren't worried about whitespace difference leading to false negatives.

Comment: If,the lists change dynamically, i.e, each line gets new numbers and some of the numbers gets deleted. Then, HashSet does not allow me to modify the lists.. ie., I cannot retrieve the list, modify it and add it back. or can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If your lines are strings you can do something like this

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "1 2 3",
                "3 4 5 6", "1 2 4 5 7", "8", "7", "1 2 4" }));
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "7",
                "3 4 5 6", "1 2 4 5 7", "1 2 3", "8", "1 2 4" }));

if (a.size() == b.size()) {
    a.removeAll(b);
    if (a.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("A and B are the same sets");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, each line has numbers and not strings. And each file changes dynamically in the memory. Supposing each time it changes, how can I update the hashsets? For the firs time, I create the list and add it to the hashset. The next time the list changes, I cannot change the list, since the hashset does not allow me to retrieve the list. how should I do this.